# Chrome extension which replaces string in body fires too late

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was making a simple extension for Chrome to replace the first occurrence of string that I find in the body tag. I placed the following code inside content.js:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Hello', 'Hi');
```

The issue is that there is a noticeable delay when original HTML is visible before the string is replaced. It is especially bad on larger web pages. Is there a way to execute it earlier that won't cause an error of body being null?

Comment: 1) Don't replace in innerHTML - it kills all javascript event listeners. 2) Declare your content script with "run_at": "document_start", 3) Run MutationObserver on `document`, enumerate the mutations and use TreeWalker API to enumerate the text nodes inside each mutation's added nodes, and replace the text inside those text nodes ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334319)).

Answer (score -2):

First of all, javascript is client sided. So you should expect that the page will load first (or the required DOM contents) before it looks for `Hello` inside the DOM.

Second, you are working for a browser extension, so you should expect that the triggers run externally.

For you to get it:

This one would be faster since you load it within the page:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<script>
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Lorem', 'Hi');
</script>
```