# How to remove elements in the content script before showing the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Here's my config:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.baidu.com/"],
      "js": ["./baidu/baidu.js"]
    }
  ]
```

And here's my `baidu.js`

```
  // #region delete useless DOM
  const deleteIdList = [
    '#s_top_wrap',
    '#bottom_layer',
    '#lm-new',
    '#s-top-left',
    '#u1',
    '#s-hotsearch-wrapper',
    '#s_side_wrapper'
  ];
  deleteIdList.forEach(v => {
    const element = document.querySelector(v);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    // element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });
```

All I want is very simple, I just hope when I visit the `baidu.com`, the useless dom can be remove(or hide). My problem is as my config works, but the useless dom will flash in the beginning. Then those disappears. I hope when I see the web, everything's ok.

I've tried to specify the attribute `run_at` as `document_start`. Then my js file do not works.

How can I make it ? (Tested in FireFox browser)

Comment: That's really complex, I don't understand bro.

Comment: For ur second plan, it works but not what I want. Because I hope the DOM's Id can be input by user. So, that's variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"run_at": "document_start"` in content script declaration is an absolute must for this.
The content script will run when the page is empty so we also need one of the following:

- observe the page being constructed by using `MutationObserver` on `document`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334319), check the added nodes and hide those that match the list of ids.
- or construct a `style` element with the selectors to hide.
  Performance-wise, it's orders of magnitude faster. Also simpler.

  ```js
  hideSelectors([
    '#s_top_wrap',
    '#bottom_layer',
    '#lm-new',
    '#s-top-left',
    '#u1',
    '#s-hotsearch-wrapper',
    '#s_side_wrapper',
  ]);

  function hideSelectors(sels) {
    const el = document.createElement('style');
    el.textContent = sels.join(',') + '{ display: none !important }';
    // there's no <head> at this point so we're adding to <html>
    // which is allowed in DOM despite violating the HTML specification
    document.documentElement.appendChild(el);
  }
  ```