# How do I add an button to the DOM once it is completely load (Chrome Extension)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension, and I want to add a button to every element in the DOM that belongs to a certain class. However, my code is executing before the DOM completely loads. How do I fix this? Below is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        // var div = document.getElementsByClassName("collection-list__page"); //[0];
        var divImg = document.getElementsByClassName("product-tile__badges");
        var button = CreateButton();
    
        for (i = 0; i < divImg.length; i++) {
          console.log(divImg);
          console.log(divImg[i].appendChild(button));
        }
    
        button.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
          button.childNodes[1].style.display = "block"; // Makes the dropdown appear
        });
    
        button.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
          button.childNodes[1].style.display = "none"; // Makes the dropdown disappear
        });
    });
```

Here is my manifest:

```
    {
      "name": "Withizze",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "content_scripts": [
          {
            "matches": ["https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "content.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
      ],
       "web_accessible_resources": ["dropDownButton.html"]
    }
```

Comment: The dom is loaded when `ready` fires so problem is more likely that elements are inserted by javascript asynchronously after it has loaded. take a look at using Mutation Observer

Comment: The element is loading after the Mutation Observer. Is. There away to get around that?

Comment: Mutation Observer listens for changes to the tree

Comment: If the code is using MutationObserver properly then the observer observes all subsequent changes. It's what MutationObserver does by definition.

Comment: @charlietfl Are there any tutorials on this?

Comment: @wOxxOm Are there any tutorials on that?

Comment: There tons of them, use google search. Here's [an example in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334319).

Comment: I got the mutation observer working! However, it is inconsistent with appending new elements to the document.